# How to pass custom event arg after user clicks a context menu's toolstrip item

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've got a dynamically filled datagrid view. When a user right clicks a cell in the datagridview, it opens a context menu, located by that cell. The context menu has two choices:  A and B. I want to set the value of the cell to A if they pick A, and B if they pick B.

I guess ideally, I would like to pass the relevant cell as a field in the event args passed to ContextMenu's ToolStripItem.click. So the handler for ToolStripItem A's click event would read the relevant cell from the event args and set it to A , like this...

```
Private Sub A_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Customized System.EventArgs) Handles A.Click
   e.relevantCell.Value=A
End Sub
```

But I can't figure out how to pass a custom event arg. Or if there is some easier way to do this? I can't just use the X and Y coordinates, because the context menu/mouse won't necessary by over the relevant cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can put the desired cell in the Tag property (which accepts objects), then at menu item click, get the cell from the tag and set it's value

Try:

```
A.Tag = Cell you want to set to A after A is clicked

Private Sub A_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles A.Click
    CType(A.Tag, DataGridViewTextBoxCell).Value = "A"
End Sub
```

Comment: But, how do I pass a custom event arg? (with a relevant cell property)

Comment: you don't need to, just set the tag, and you are ok

Comment: but event args dont normally have a relevantCell field. I would have to set up this property of event args.

Comment: I got it to work by setting the Tag property to the relevant cell (not to a string as you suggest). This answer was really close so I accepted it and tweaked it so that it actually solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the sender argument as the ToolStripItem and then use that object to determine type A or B.

```
If CType(sender, ToolStripItem).Text = "A" Then 'Or Text of A

  'Work to Update Cell

End If
```

Comment: But how do I get the relevant cell?